# How to flatten some PDF form fields but not all of them

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, docusignapi

I am using C# and iTextSharp for PDFs. I have a PDF template that has form fields for information and also form fields for electronic signatures. I need to be able to have staff fill our part of the form, then in code, flatten that part (leaving the signature fields alone) and then I will be passing off the PDF to DocuSign's API to have the user sign the document electronically.

I have requirements that only the fields that should be editable by the user (signature) are form fields when they reach the DocuSign API. I have to flatten all the other fields before passing it to the DocuSign API (DocuSign automatically can Tag form fields for Signature).

Does anyone know how to do this? I have thought about getting the position of the signature fields, and after flattening the whole PDF adding the form fields back in with iTextSharp, but I feel that is a hack.

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to flatten a specific field rather than the whole document then I believe you can use the following:

```
Stamper.FormFlattening = true;
Stamper.PartialFormFlattening("FieldName");
```

The only downside to this method is that you need to list every field that needs to be flattened.  I think they are required to contain a value as well (i.e. you can't flatten a blank field).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify the names of the filed you want to update just take a look at the following example.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001747/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030211-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following page from DocuSign's REST API guide as it has some good info on what you can do with the Adobe form fields and some special cases:

http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm

Answer (score 0):

For XFA form you get

> Partial form flattening is not supported with XFA forms.

exception if you use `PartialFormFlattening`.

To flat some fields I used

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(fieldName, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
```

make sure you use full fieldName (for instance for [W-9](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf) Name field use "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_1[0]" not "f1_1") otherwise it won't work.

I also tried remove XFA with

```
PdfDictionary acro =
   (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(
           pdfReader.Catalog.Get(PdfName.ACROFORM));
                acro.Remove(PdfName.XFA);
```

as it described [here](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/How-to-partial-flatten-a-XFA-Form-td2160771.html) but I got the same exception.